# YAML merge multiple arrays into one

Tags: arrays, list, merge, yaml

I'm trying to merge arrays/lists into one big list, but there is always missing elements:

```
commonFields: &commonFields
- {label: title}
- {label: url}

extraFields: &extraFields
- {label: blocks}
- {label: hide}

metaFields: &metaFields
- {label: robots}
- {label: description}

fields:
- <<: *commonFields
- <<: *metaFields
- <<: *extraFields
```

yaml online parser with this example: [link](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=commonFields%3A%20%26commonFields%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20title%7D%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20url%7D%0A%0AextraFields%3A%20%26extraFields%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20blocks%7D%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20hide%7D%0A%0AmetaFields%3A%20%26metaFields%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20robots%7D%0A-%20%7Blabel%3A%20description%7D%0A%0Afields%3A%0A-%20%3C%3C%3A%20*commonFields%0A-%20%3C%3C%3A%20*metaFields%0A-%20%3C%3C%3A%20*extraFields&type=json)

Answer (score 1):

The [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is an optional extension to outdated YAML 1.1. Let's discuss what happens in the first item:

```
- <<: *commonFields
```

The spec says:

> If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence.

`*commonFields` references a sequence, so this rule is applicable: We merge each mapping in the referenced sequence into the current mapping (the current mapping is `<<: *commonFields`). Merging the first sequence results in

```
- label: title
```

Then, we merge the second mapping. Now this rule applies:

> If the value associated with the key is a single mapping node, each of its key/value pairs is inserted into the current mapping, **unless the key already exists in it.**

Our mapping already has a key *label*, so the key-value pair `label: url` from the second mapping is not merged.

---

You probably misunderstood what `<<` does. It merges mappings into *the mapping it is part of itself*. It does not merge sequence items into the parent sequence of this mapping. There is no way in standard YAML to do that and no extensions I know of do it (even `<<` is not standard YAML).

You could define a local tag to do it, e.g.:

```
fields: !flatten
- *commonFields
- *metaFields
- *extraFields
```

However, you would need to implement the `!flatten` tag yourself in the code that loads this YAML.

Alternatively, you can do what everyone else does and use a templating engine to pre-process your YAML (Jinja2, Liquid, etc).

Comment: thank you @flyx. I was hoping for this simplest solution, but seems i will have to use preprocessing, because i cant control that yaml parser.